# ERROR: Tag Mismatch while Gradle build when adding Dagger 2(v2.11)

Tags: android, build.gradle, dagger-2, dagger

I'm getting **TAG MISMATCH Error** when adding **Dagger 2 (v2.11) dependencies** in app level build.gradle file. Searched a lot on Google but not getting the reason of this error.

Anybody have idea about this problem??

This is dependencies in my app-level build.gradle file ->

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

def daggerVersion = '2.11'
def fireBaseVersion = '11.2.2'
def supportLibraryVersion = '26.0.1'

compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVersion"

compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:customtabs:$supportLibraryVersion"
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
/*compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"*/

compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$fireBaseVersion"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$fireBaseVersion"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$fireBaseVersion"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:$fireBaseVersion"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:$fireBaseVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$fireBaseVersion"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:$fireBaseVersion"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$fireBaseVersion"

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'}
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question unless you actually post your `build.gradle`. Try and create an [MCVE]

Comment: @DavidRawson Hey I have updated my Question.. have a look.. I have added dependencies list in my gradle file .

Comment: Where is the full error message?

Comment: @DavidRawson It's only Tag Mismatch, Gradle error...